# Rejecting a paypal payment

Tags: c#, paypal

I'm currently implementing an Automation system for software selling through Paypal API. I have got the IPN portal working so it recieves IPN Messages from Paypal and is passed to a back-end service which files it in a SQL DB, Generates a license yadda yadda yadda. It also checks against an internal entry to confirm the payment recieved matches the actual price of the product purchased (Stopping them sneaky hackers). I have now got to a stumbling block where i would like to reject payments that are the incorrect price and i've trawled the Paypal API Developer documentation and can't seem to find what i'm after. My guess is making a call to the Adaptive or merchant API URLs but I cant find what info past auth credentials i'd need to send. Can anyone point me to the right page or 3rd party website with the information I can use to get this setup? an NVP solution would be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really reject a payment at that point because the transaction has already been completed. All you can do is refund it, which you can do via the [RefundTransaction API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/RefundTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) within your IPN script.  This way you'll also get your PayPal fee refunded.

You've already got your logic in place to check if the prices match, so just add a call to RefundTransaction if the price does not match.  You may also want to send an email notification to the buyer in such cases letting them know something was wrong with the pricing on their order so it's been refunded, and maybe even provide a checkout button for them to re-buy at the correct price if you want to.

Comment: Beautiful, Right on the money, thanks for this article!

Comment: Hi Andrew, Quick question, Should The Merchant API be authentication with X-PAYPAL headers, or api USER/PWD NVP entries?

Comment: Pretty much everything outside of Adaptive Payments and the REST API use the user/pass/sig combo.